# how to get all checkboxes from one of three forms?

Tags: javascript, forms, checkbox

I have three forms, each of them has checkboxes and submit button. I need to get all checkbox names or id by clicking on the submit button in only this form.
And for other two also.

```
function getCheckedBoxes(item) {
    var checkboxes = document.getElementsByName(item);
    var checkboxesChecked = [];
    // loop over them all
    for (var i=0; i<checkboxes.length; i++) {
        // And stick the checked ones onto an array...
        if (checkboxes[i].checked) {
            checkboxesChecked.push(checkboxes[i]);
        }
    }
    // Return the array if it is non-empty, or null
    console.log(checkboxes);
    return checkboxesChecked.length > 0 ? checkboxesChecked : null;
}

var inp = document.getElementsByName('send');
for(var i = 0; i < inp.length; i++){
    inp[i].addEventListener('click', function(e) {
        getCheckedBoxes("item");
        e.preventDefault();
    });
}
```

example of my checkboxes

```
<form>
    <input id="check29" type="checkbox" name="item" value="29" />
    <input class="lab-btn" type="submit" value="ADD ALL" name="send">
</form>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can pass the form as a parameter to the function, then use querySelectorAll to get all of its inputs with the desired name.

So first, change the event handler to this:

```
inp[i].addEventListener('click', function(e) {
    getCheckedBoxes(this.form, "item");
    e.preventDefault();
});
```

Then the function itself to:

```
function getCheckedBoxes(oForm, item) {
    var checkboxes = oForm.querySelectorAll('input[name="' + item + '"]');
    //...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

To select all checboxes on a page you can use:

```
var checkboxes = document.querySelectorAll("input[type=checkbox]");

// And for all checkboxes in a form:
var checkboxesInForm = form.querySelectorAll("input[type=checkbox]");
```

See https://developer.mozilla.org/nl/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll for documentation.

Does this answer your question?